# Screen Locks Continuously

Tags: android

I made a application to lock the screen. I write a code to lock the screen in a onCreate() method of activity,

Here the screen is locked correctly, but as I run application it locks the screen, now when I unlock it, it again shows the activity and then again lock the screen, so I can not do anything no what should I do.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Comment: It seems your activity is being destroyed when you lock the screen and when u unlock it its always created so onCreate method is called since you lock screen in onCreate your app always lock the screen BTW the code you posted is related to screen brightness which let the screen black not of locking the screen

Comment: question and given source-code don't match ...

Comment: if in the android screen brightness is set to level 0 then it locks

Comment: That's only on certain devices can be very problematic on others. For example, some devices actually do set the brightness to 0, but leave the device on, so you don't know what's going on.

Comment: then how do i make the brightness to 0, i want to make the flashing screen

Comment: Is there any code other then this to lock the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think ur application is actually locking the screen. Its just turnig it OFF. When u try to unlock the screen, the screen is turning ON( due to user interaction ). As ur application is still running its forcing the sceern to turn OFF again. Just a wild guess, sorry if i mk completely wrong!!

Comment: Try this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#lock